# Book recommendations for Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

What is the best mathematics book for studying geometry from nothing to complete under $15?
I like reading physical books. Please don't recommend any online site or e-book.
Note: I don't know anything about trigonometry.

Comment: gelfand textbook

Comment: Gelfand is great. Hard to get "complete" geometry from one book. "Trigonometry Refresher" by Klaf is available in a cheap Dover reprint, it is mostly problem based. Seidenberg's "Projective Geometry" is also available cheap from Dover, but is a projective geometry book. Dover is a publisher that is likely to hit your price point.

Comment: @leslietownes "Dover is **the only** publisher that is likely to hit your price point."  (At the risk of coming across like a jerk, "fixed that for you"). :P

Comment: @XA01 You say you don't know trigonometry.  What *do* you know?  What is your background?

Comment: I am very good in algebra and know geometry enough for Trigonometry.    As for background....I am very poor amd never went to school but I like mathematics  so was am learning on my own.

Comment: You can sometimes find used math books at very good prices.  If there is a used book store near you, look there.  If not, look online.